# Kinect Azure Body Tracking Coordinate Mapping

Tags: azurekinect

I am wondering, is there is a way to get Joint Position in color and depth space, similar to the v2 coordinate mapper MapCameraPointToColorSpace and MapCameraPointToDepthSpace?

Also how can I map the body index image to color image?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The [k4abt_skeleton_t](https://microsoft.github.io/Azure-Kinect-Body-Tracking/release/0.9.x/structk4abt__skeleton__t.html) from [Azure Kinect Body Tracking SDK](https://microsoft.github.io/Azure-Kinect-Body-Tracking/release/0.9.x/index.html) provides 3D joint locations in the depth camera space. You can project the skeleton joints into the color sensor space using the provided 3d to 2d conversion APIs from the [Azure Kinect Sensor SDK](https://microsoft.github.io/Azure-Kinect-Sensor-SDK/master/index.html).

- [k4a_calibration_3d_to_2d](https://microsoft.github.io/Azure-Kinect-Sensor-SDK/master/group___functions_ga2ed8b51d727425caa942aab190fc2ba9.html#ga2ed8b51d727425caa942aab190fc2ba9)
- [k4a::calibration::convert_3d_to_2d](https://microsoft.github.io/Azure-Kinect-Sensor-SDK/master/structk4a_1_1calibration_a74a6fef25540e9cdf18ed06ff1cfdc2e.html#a74a6fef25540e9cdf18ed06ff1cfdc2e)

*"Transform a 3D point of a source coordinate system into a 2D pixel coordinate of the target camera."*

For transforming the body index image to the RGB image, take a look at the following APIs in the [Azure Kinect Sensor SDK](https://microsoft.github.io/Azure-Kinect-Sensor-SDK/master/index.html):

- [k4a::transformation::depth_image_to_color_camera_custom](https://microsoft.github.io/Azure-Kinect-Sensor-SDK/master/classk4a_1_1transformation_a81ead7ffe1c9540a2f91c364a749827d.html#a81ead7ffe1c9540a2f91c364a749827d)
- [k4a_transformation_depth_image_to_color_camera_custom](https://microsoft.github.io/Azure-Kinect-Sensor-SDK/master/group___functions_gac00dd00e7612a86382e3d0a130f276bb.html#gac00dd00e7612a86382e3d0a130f276bb)

*"Transforms depth map and a custom image into the geometry of the color camera.*"

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am using the c# API. I managed to get the joint positions from calibration but transformation.DepthImageToColorCamera(bodyIndexImage) throws the exception Invalid argument to image_create(). Do this work in c API?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that MapCameraPointToColorSpace and MapCameraPointToDepthSpace are replaced by Calibration TransfromTo2D.

I haven't found a solution for mapping the body index image.